# Source code dependency is minified in Create React App due to module key in package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a blank Create React App is created and the [MidiConvert](https://github.com/Tonejs/MidiConvert/) library is a dependency, it is fine for developing. As soon as a build is started it gives the following error indicating it tries to minify the source file:

```
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

    ./node_modules/midiconvert/src/Util.js:20

Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

In the package.json from MidiConvert the following entry triggers the build of the source files.

```
"module": "src/MidiConvert.js",
```

When removed, the React project builds.

Relevant links:

- [React project implementing MidiConvert](https://github.com/Wintergatan/midipunch-react)
- [Travis error build log](https://travis-ci.org/Wintergatan/midipunch-react/builds/341596173)
- [Package JSON with erroring line of MidiConvert](https://github.com/Tonejs/MidiConvert/blob/master/package.json#L6)